# How can I read slash when I use read_csv in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file like this:

```
Date
2020/01/22 16:47:37
2020/01/22 16:47:37
.....
```

but when I use read_csv function  I get

```
0         Jan 22 16:47:37
1         Jan 22 16:47:37
2         Jan 22 16:47:37
```

How can I read slash when I use read_csv in pandas?

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd


data=pd.read_csv(path+file,
                 encoding='utf-8-sig',
                 sep=',')
```

Comment: your delimiter is whitespace, so pass sep = '  ' instead of ','

Comment: Problem is if test data in excel?

Comment: @sammywemmy I already test sep='' ,but still have error

Comment: @jezrael successfully if file in excel ,why csv can't read it?

Comment: What is your context? What do you need this for? Can you use `strftime`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
pd.read_csv('filepath',sep='\t')
```

instead of `sep=' '`